# Взаимодействие с кнопкой с использованием ObjectName

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, findchildren, objectname

Задача в том, что нужно сделать неактивной кнопку, используя ***только*** **`ObjectName`**.

У нас есть эта кнопка:

```py
save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox) 
save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 180, 81, 25))
save.setObjectName('save_1')
save.setText("Save")
save.clicked.connect(lambda ch, obj = self.setting_num: self.save_frame(obj))
```

Я знаю, что если эта задача выполняется с использованием имени переменной, это можно написать так:

```py
save.setEnabled(False)
```

Я нигде не нашел хорошего примера, благодаря которому можно было бы реализовать мою задачу. Буду очень рад, если кто-то сможет помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно найти виджет через метод [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild), например:

```
button = self.findChild(QObject, 'save_1')
button.setEnabled(False)
```

Чтобы поиск сработал, нужно чтобы виджет уже был добавлен в иерархии виджетов, например находясь в компоновщике, которые находится в текущем виджете. Или с явно указанным родителем `self`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло

Comment: @ITProgram, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Почему вы не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример?
Вы должны более полно объяснять что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Мне кажется что вам надо при связке событий с сигналом надо передавать не `objectName()`, 
а объект экземпляра кнопки:

```
save.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=save: self.save_frame(btn))
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):             
        super().__init__()

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(3):
            
            groupBox = QGroupBox(f'groupBox_{i}', self)  
            groupBox.setObjectName(f'groupBox_{i}')
            
            textEdit = QTextEdit(objectName=f'textEdit_{i}')
            textEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda i=i: self.text_changed(i))
            
            save = QPushButton("Save", groupBox, objectName=f'save_{i}') 
            save.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
            save.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D8F8B7;')
#            save.clicked.connect(lambda ch, obj=save.objectName(): self.save_frame(obj))
            save.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=save: self.save_frame(btn))
# ----------------------------------------->^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^
            
            layout = QVBoxLayout(groupBox)
            layout.addWidget(textEdit)
            layout.addWidget(save)
            
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(groupBox)

# ---------------------> vvv
    def save_frame(self, btn): 
        print(f'{btn.objectName()}') #
# ----> vvv
        btn.setEnabled(False)
        btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: #FF9A8C;')
        
    def text_changed(self, i): 
        button = self.findChild(QObject, f'save_{i}')
        button.setEnabled(True)
        button.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D8F8B7;')
    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое Спасибо!